# Linked lists with no data and a self referential pointer

Tags: linux-kernel, linked-list

```
kernel/include/linux/types.h

.....
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

struct hlist_head {
    struct hlist_node *first;
};

struct hlist_node {
    struct hlist_node *next, **pprev;
};
```

What purpose these lists containing no data serve?

Answer (score 0):

These are generic lists that can be used to link any data structure. Say for example, I have a structure

```
strut my_data {
    type1;
    type2;
    ...
    struct list_head list;
    ...
    typen;
};
```

And I have another list head,

```
struct list_head head;
```

I am initializing it to reference itself

```
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&head);
```

Now I can add an element to it

```
list_add_tail(&my_data.list, &head);
```

And the structure is linked now, to get the element back, we can use the `list_entry` API, which will internally call `container_of` function. There are other useful APIs used to loop through the list and perform operation, which can be found along with their implementation in `kernel/include/list.h`.